# When overriding SaveChanges and removing the EF relationship is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

In my many-to-one relationship I am trying to delete one of the child objects and keep an audit trail in my overridden SaveChanges.

The file.Entity.Product is not null when doing an EntityState.Modified or EntityState.Added but when doing a .Deleted EF seems to be aggressively removing the relationship from the entity even before base.Savechanges() is called.

Is there any way to retrieve when Product this file was associated with in my SaveChanges override after I have called .Remove on the File (child)?

```cs
var files = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries<SavedFile>()
                    where e.State != EntityState.Unchanged
                    select e;
if (file.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                var text = "File Deleted: " + file.Entity.FriendlyFileName;
                // file.Entity.Product is null
                var updatedProduct = new Update { Product = file.Entity.Product, UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now, UpdateText = text, User = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name };
                Updates.Add(updatedProduct);
            }
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is a `foreach` loop over `files` assigning the value of `file`, right?

Comment: you can store the required fields in properties and mark it NotMapped or Ingnore if you are using fluid mapping

Answer (score 2):

Just as you find the file in the `ChangeTracker`'s entries, you can find its product, assuming that `File` has a *foreign key association* with `Product`, i.e. it has a `ProductID` property besides a `Product` navigation property:

```
if (file.State == EntityState.Deleted)
{
    var text = "File Deleted: " + file.Entity.FriendlyFileName;
    var productEntry = ChangeTracker.Entries<Product>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Entity.ID == file.ProductID);
    if (productEntry != null)
    {
        var updatedProduct = new Update { Product = productEntry.Entity, UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now, UpdateText = text, User = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name };
        Updates.Add(updatedProduct);
    }
}
```

It's expected behavior that EF doesn't show deleted entities whenever entities are queries from the local cache (e.g. `DbSet.Local`). So it also has to break associations to prevent these entities from appearing in navigation properties. If you delete a file, EF won't display it in `context.Files.Local`, but neither will it be visible in a navigation property like `product.Files` (and neither will the other side of the association, `file.Product`).

Comment: in this way you are querying the database again!

Comment: Not at all. I'm querying `ChangeTracker.Entries<Product>()`.

Comment: the down vote is locked, edit this answer in order to be able to vote up

Comment: I effectively used your method but I had to do a little tweaking to get it work.  I had to turn on eager loading, setup a foreign key association and I had to load all of the entries as attempt to cast them as "Product" since calling .Entries<Product>() would always result in null. I'll post my full solution on Monday.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm interested in seeing why `Entries<Product>()` didn't work as expected. That would mean that no unchanged `Product`s were present (?). But then they shouldn't need auditing -- well, I'll see...

Comment: This solution did end up working I just had to remove the check on **p.State != EntityState.Unchanged** as @kiran mentioned in their solution. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: OK, so you also want to log the product if only the fie is deleted, yes of course (face palm).

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no way to access the relation ship after deletion

but, why don't you use the soft delete, which is the best practice in my opinion, at any time you can return back the deleted record if was deleted mistakenly ( by marking IsDeleted = false, by the admin with authority)

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for just the `Product` property, you could capture it with some custom logic on its definition:

```
class File {
   ...
   private Product product;
   private Product lastProduct;

   public Product Product {
      get { return product; }
      set {
          if (product == value) return;
          lastProduct = Product;
          product = value;
      }
   }

   [NotMapped]
   public Product LastProduct {
      get { return lastProduct; }
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Gert Arnold should work - but not sure whether it makes sense to check
     FirstOrDefault(p => **p.State != EntityState.Unchanged**
as the related entity might be still in ***Unchanged*** status.

**If nothing works,** try reloading the entity in the overridden SaveChanges method.

```
this.Entry((file.Entity as <<Your Entity Type>>)).Reload();
//do your operation/audit log
//then reset the Entity State to Deleted
this.Entry((file.Entity)).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

**Edit: or explicit load just the required related entities alone**

```
this.Entry(file.Entity as <Type>).Reference(e=> e.Product).Load();
```

*This would end up in an extra db hit while Reload.*

**Edit: Another option, again if no other good options found**

How about executing raw SQL insert query in this scenario to populate audit table?

Comment: Loading entities can have all kinds of side effects. Not a good idea to do this while saving changes. And if that didn't matter, this also makes `SaveChanges` a potentially expensive operation.

Comment: @GertArnold- True, I just meant doing this only for deleted entities though..that's why I kinda specified *if nothing works*; was thinking of a worst case scenario where lazy loading was disabled and the related entities were not eager/explicitly loaded; then probably hitting db is the only option in this case. As I mentioned, your answer should work; tried up-voting your answer, but couldn't do that being a newbie here...seems like I need some score to do voting :)

Comment: Another scenario where I think querying ChangeTracker would fail is in disconnected one. The context which fetched the details might have got disposed after the get operation and when the delete operation is performed, that could be in a different context. So what if we just did context.Entry(<entity>). State = EntityState.Deleted? Not sure the related entity/navigational property details would be there in the change tracker..just thinking aloud...

Comment: If the OP talks about *aggressively removing the relationship from the entity* I assume the relationship was there first. If not, they'll have to get the entity from the database anyway in order delete it.